# I know how to masking half of the part of email using rgx_exp, but i want to know how to mask half of the phone number using egx_exp in sql?

Tags: sql

[image]

------------im using this one masking email------------

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MASKING POLICY PERSONAL_INFO.Email_Policy AS (email string) returns string ->
case when current_role() in ('MASK_ADMIN') then email
when current_role() in ('ACCOUNTADMIN') then regexp_replace(email,'.+\@','*****@')
else '**Masked Email**'
END;


ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERDETAILS MODIFY COLUMN email set MASKING POLICY PERSONAL_INFO.Email_Policy;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).